# Connect with Powershell to MSSQL over HAproxy

Tags: sql-server, haproxy, ubuntu-20.04, windows-server-2012-r2

I have PowerShell script running on Ubuntu 20.04 which I want to talk to MSSQL running on MS Server 2012 R2.

I can connect to MSSQL from Ubuntu 16.04 with exact same setup, but from U2004 getting

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

After some digging figured out that Ubuntu and MS Server cannot agree on encryption/ciphers. In fact Ubuntu 2004 don't support list of ciphers which MSSQL is offering.

Tried to build on U2004 earlier version of openssl to get weak ciphers enabled, but that didn't work (and not recommended btw as that may break other OS dependencies ...).

My next bet is to get HAproxy running on Ubuntu 16.04 and forward traffic from Ubuntu 20.04 to MSSQL through it. The idea is to enable support of weak ciphers on 'backend'. In fact I know that 'AES256-SHA' is supported by MSSQL.

My config is the following:

```
frontend sql-db
    bind 192.168.100.3:1433
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global
    default_backend connToDB

backend connToDB
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global
    server DB-1 db1:1433 ciphers AES256-SHA
```

But still getting the same

> provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed

If I do `server DB-1 db1:1433 ssl verify none ciphers AES256-SHA` (which I found fixes issues sometimes but seems only for http proxy) then I am getting

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=3; handshake=15058;

Playing with openssl.conf on Ubuntu 20.04 (setting minsslversion and defining ciphers) also didn't help.

P.S. **Any changes to MSSQL are not currently possible**! That would be the way to fix it, but unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Ok after battling with the issue for couple of days I finally figured it out.
Just append `openssl_conf = default_conf` at the beginning (!!!) of openssl.cnf file and append at the end of file:

```
[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

I already tried that solution previously but my mistake was that I had `openssl_conf = default_conf` line not at the upmost top of the file and because of that this solution didn't work for me. (-_-)

Handy approach to test config without rebooting host - create `/path/to/my/file/openssl_test.cnf` with the config you want to use.
Then simply prepend the command you need to run in bash with `OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/my/file/openssl_test.cnf` so it looks something like (in my case with Linux powershell):

`OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/my/file/openssl_test.cnf pwsh myScript.ps1 arg1 arg2`